# FileMaker - Does an onRecordCommit Trigger Fire on Imports?

Tags: triggers, filemaker

I can't seem to find this in any of the documentation.

I have a script that gets triggered on layout > onRecordCommit.

I'm curious if it will also be triggered during a data import to that table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was curious too, so I just tested it in FM11 and no, the trigger doesn't fire.

After a success import you could run a script which loops through all of the records to perform the same actions of the triggered script.

Comment: Thanks.  I'd have to imagine FM10 would be the same too, right?

Comment: I didn't actually test it in FM10 but I'd be very surprised if it acted any different.

Comment: I realized my "import" process is actually running a script that goes through the steps of creating each new record.  In this case it DOES fire the onRecordCommit trigger.  I'm guessing you tried a straight import?

Comment: Yea I just did a direct import, not scripted at all.